# Using TestNG parameter values with other methods

Tags: java, testng

I was wondering how I can use the parameters used for `TestNG`.

For example, if i have

```
@org.testng.annotations.Parameters(value = {"browser", "version", "os"})
public static foo() {
    ...
}
```

Can I pass these values somewhere else in the code to be used?

ex:

```
   System.out.println(value[0]);
   System.out.println(value[1]);
   System.out.println(value[2]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the parameter argument list  you should pass the mapping param names from XML file.you may not directly pass the values in the code.

```
@org.testng.annotations.Parameters({"browserType", "version", "os"})
public static foo(String browserType,Stirng version,String operatinSystem) {

can play with values inside the functions
    ...
}
```

This is format which TestNG Framework allows you handle with parameter class